# How to declare an instance variable in Javascript / nodejs?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am running a daemon with an hourly frequency. This code, should keep track of all orphaned clients and if a client has remained orphaned for 12 hours it should be deleted. The code runs with an hourly frequency thus I need data to be saved per hour so that it is available in the next hour.  Since I am new to javascript, I have made an attempt to declare a global var **deleteOrphanedClients = new Map();**. 
Will my following global variable **deleteOrphanedClients** be saved and be available each time the code is triggered ?

````
var deleteOrphanedClients = new Map();

// Delete idle client without any parent.  
exports.cleanupClients = function (clients, callback) {
    for (int i = 0; i < clients.length; i++) {
        // this checks if client is orphaned.
        if (clients[i]["parent"] == undefined) {
            if (deleteOrphanedClients[clients[i]] == undefined) {
                deleteOrphanedClients[clients[i]] = new Date();
            }
        }
    }

    // delete all clients older than 12 hours from deleteOrphanedClients
};

var manager = function (cb) {

    async.series(
        [
            function (callback) {

                async.series(
                    [
                        function (cbi) {
                            // get clients.
                        },
                        function (cbi) {
                            cleanupClients();
                        },
                    ],
                    function (err, results) {
                        callback(err, results);
                    }
                );
            }
        ],
    );
};

exports.manager = manager;

var randomInt = function (low, high) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (high - low + 1) + low);
};

var pause = randomInt(0, 60);
setTimeout(
    function () {
        setInterval(manager, 36000 * 1000,
            function (err, results) {
                if (err) {
                    logError(err);
                }
            });
    }, pause * 1000);```
````

Comment: Have you tried running it? As long as the program continues running and `deleteOrphanedClients` is in scope, it will be available. Can you elaborate what the question is a bit more? Thanks. You might be confusing `Map` with a basic object, though. Use `.get`/`.set` instead of brackets.

Comment: If your node.js process ends (which it sounds like it does between runs), then your deleteOrphanedClients var will disappear, because you have not specifically saved it to the file system (or somewhere). Then you will also need to restore it from the file system at the next run.